# Documentation for VMware NSX RESTful API

Tags: vmware-vsphere

We are gonna develop some feature for our product for which we need to leverage the VMware NSX API. First we want to understand the API and the `RPC`'s. But we are not able to find any documentation for NSX API.

Can any body help us ?

Answer (score 2):

Contact VMWare directly, if you explain what you're trying to do and register as a developer they'll let you have all the documentation and support you need. We're deploying this right now and they've been very helpful, although they do admit that the regular publically-available documentation is a little thin on the ground but that's because this is one of their "professional services lead' products rather than 'end user lead'.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is publicly available [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/NSX-62/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/nsx_62_api.pdf).